# Returning a list of directories, and then printing off every image for every instance of a directory with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop

I'm attempting to create a kind of file tree with jQuery and AJAX that looks through a directory, finds every instance of a folder and then create a for loop that returns the name of every file within each iteration of a folder.

Someone else was able to tell me that "an ajax call never triggers another ajax call" and that the for loop logistically couldn't work. So I guess I'm asking how else I'm supposed to pull this off.

The following is a stripped-back version of my code.

```
dir = 'Images/';

fol = [];

file = [];

// finds every instance of a folder, inserts it into an array
$.ajax({
  url: dir,
  success: function(data) {

    $(data).find('a:contains("/")').each(function() {

      fol.push(this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http:///", "").split('/')[1]);

    });

  }

});

// (I'd like to) find every instance of an image, return its filename and insert it into an array
for (var i = 0; i < fol.length; i++) {

$.ajax({
  url: dir + fol[i],
  success: function(data) {

    $(data).find('a').each(function() {

        file.push(this.href.replace(window.location, "").replace("http:///", ""));
    });

  }

}

});

}
```

Comment: Ok if you use php .. do all your stuff in php file which you call it by ajax .. and then use .html in ajax success to render it in your page .. and use just one ajax to do that

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm required to do it all via JavaScript.